# How to fake scroll in angular2 using buttons?

Tags: angular

If I have a div 300x300, in addition to a scrollbar if the content exceeds the height of the box (so that vertical scrollbar appears) (overflow: auto), I want to have a button that appears stuck to the bottom of the box that says "Page Down" and a button that appears stuck to the top of the box that says "Page Up" that will "virtually scroll" as if the user had clicked on the scrollbar based on the height of a div.

I want this to be usable for divs. What is a good way to implement this? Is this a directive does duplicate code need to be added for each component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist [Custom scroll angular directives](https://www.google.es/#q=angular+2+custom+scroll+directives). I think also you could customize its to more specific purposes.

I used once [ng2-slimscroll](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-slimscroll) and it contains 1 only directive I think you could edit to add a function and manage the button you wish action.

You will notice it is using javascript common functions to calculate scroll height and so on. Here a sample of the function it uses to calculate barHeight. You can find in their github project folder.  [ng2-slimscroll/src/directives/slimscroll.directive.ts](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-slimscroll/blob/master/src/directives/slimscroll.directive.ts)

```
 getBarHeight(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let barHeight = Math.max((this.el.offsetHeight / this.el.scrollHeight) * this.el.offsetHeight, 30) + 'px';
      let display = parseInt(barHeight, 10) === this.el.offsetHeight ? 'none' : 'block';

      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.bar, 'height', barHeight);
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.bar, 'display', display);
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.grid, 'display', display);
    }, 1);
}
```